# Cron hourly after boot time

Tags: linux, centos7, centos6, cron, systemd

Is there anyway to execute cron hourly after boot time and not at a specific time every hour? I am working with CentOS6 and CentOS 7 machines.

E.G.: When my computer boots at 00:42 I want it to be executed at 01:42, 02:42, 03:42 and so on. But when the computer starts at 00:21, I want cron to be executed at 01:21, 02:21, 03:21 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [systemd timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) can be scheduled for an interval respective to system boot/start time with the `OnActiveSec=`, `OnBootSec=`, `OnStartupSec=`, `OnUnitActiveSec=` options

```
/etc/systemd/system/your-notcron-hourly.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run Something every hour respective to systemd start time

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=1h 

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think cron can do this but you can do with some bash magick.:)

You can get the boot minute from `/proc/uptime` after some converstation

```
date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +%M
```

So you can use `/etc/cron.d/your-script` somewhat like this:

```
* * * * * user /bin/bash -c "if [[ $(date +%M) == $(date -d \"`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago\" +%M) ]]; then do-my-job; fi"
```